# Why can't I see my Lightning Component tab in my Custom App?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I created a Lightning Component Tab.

Added this tab to Standard apps - Sales, Call center, Marketing and also to a Custom app. I can see the tab in Sales, Call Center and Marketing apps but not in Custom App.

Is this something a salesforce limitation or am I missing something? Initially it worked suddenly I do not see it in the Custom app.